# How to load a .o file at runtime in C++?

Tags: c++, plugins, linker, loader, dynamic-linking

I'm writing a plugin library in C++ and need to call a remote function which is not defined (only declared) at the time of compilation of the host program.

I need the host program to call a function in plugin program but I also need the flexibility of compiling host program at one time and plugin program later and get the host to run a remote function from plugin.

Here's a basic implementation of my solution:

I made these 3 files:

host.cpp:

```
#include "plug.h"

int main() {

    cout<<"Hello World!"<<endl;

    remoteFunction();
    return 0;
}
```

plug.cpp:

```
#include "plug.h"

void remoteFunction() {
    cout<<"in Remote"<<endl;
    return;
}
```

plug.h:

```
void remoteFunction(void);
```

Then I compiled `plug.cpp` using `g++ -c plug.cpp` to generate `plug.o`.

Now I can use `g++ host.cpp -o executable plug.o` to get a single executable file which runs fine. But this way I need to fully define the remote function beforehand. **How do I get `host.cpp` to compile without compiling `plug.cpp` first.**

If there are some completely different ways to get this functionality, suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: What you need is a *dynamic library* or *shared object file*. Have you ever looked in e.g. `/usr/lib` and seen all those files ending in `.so`? That's the thing you need to create. Go to your favorite search engine and search for *shared object file in linux* (for example). Then read about the [`dlopen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and [`dlsym`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) functions for the actual dynamic loading.

Comment: I can get this to work with shared libraries, but is that a good practice for plugins?

I feel uncomfortable making changes to my `/usr/lib` folder every time someone adds a plugin to my program.

Comment: The [`dlopen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) function can take any path, so you can put the shared object anywhere you like. Please read the manual pages I linked to, and search for how to make shared objects. I mentioned `/usr/lib` only for example where you can find plenty of shared object files, I don't mean that you should place your own files there (or in any `lib` directory), you could just as easily have `/opt/yourproject/plugins` as the plugin installation directory or any arbitrary path.